# Why is HorizontalScrollView scrolling to right?

Tags: android, android-edittext, horizontalscrollview

The below XML contains an EditText control. As soon as I touch it, the softkeyboard appears but the HorizontalScrollView scrolls to the right so I cannot see the EditText!

Can somebody please tell me what is wrong with the below XML and why it is doing this?

Please excuse hardcoded widths - this is only a test bit of code for sanity checking.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<HorizontalScrollView 
  android:id="@+id/testScrollView"
  android:layout_width="1280dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:scrollbars="horizontal"
  android:background="#00FF00">

  <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="2560dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout 
      android:id="@+id/mLeftBaseLinearLayout"
      android:layout_width="1280dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="#FF0000">

     <EditText
       android:id="@+id/mEditText"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:background="#BBBBBB"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="EditText"
       android:textColor="#FFFF00"
       android:textSize="30dp"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:editable="true"
       android:focusable="true"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
       android:inputType="text"/>

     <ListView          
       android:id="@+id/mListView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="#80FFFFFF" >
     </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
      android:id="@+id/linLayout"
      android:layout_width="1280dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="#00FF00">

      <Button
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" />

      <Button
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2" />            

    </LinearLayout>        

  </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

My tablet is running Android 4.2.1

Comment: I don't know if it is a good idea to have HorizontalScrollView as a root? Are you using it as a fragment? What do you do with the scroller in your code? This line looks like a candidate for trouble: android:layout_width="1280dp"

Comment: @Millthorn: OK, I put the HorizontalScrollView into a root FrameLayout - same thing. Why do you think the 1280dp line is a candidate for trouble? I think the next best thing for me to do is get the source code for HorizontalScrollView and make my own version that doesn't have this jump/autofocus behaviour.

Comment: regarding the size: According to my own thinking your scroller should never be bigger than the screen. If you load this layout and it does not fit, I would suspect that strange things happen. Why not mach_parent and if needed set the weigth for the siblings.

Comment: @Millthorn: I have tried match_parent as well. Lastnight I was experimenting with scroll windows even smaller than the screen but didn't have any luck there either :-( I had a quick look at the HorizontalScrollView source. May be a bit of a fiddle getting a copy of it to build but that looks to be the only way - there are methods contained within that I cannot override so I'll give that a go unless somebody can come up with the smoking gun :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution - override scrollTo() and do absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have been looking at your layout and made a few changes and it looks ok on my computer.

Firstly, mEditText is unnecessary and avoidable. If you want a header for mListView

```
yourListView.addHeaderView(View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable);
```

This is what I did:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/testScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mLeftBaseLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#BBBBBB"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:editable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="EditText"
                android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/mListView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#80FFFFFF" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#00FF00"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

If this does not work we need to look at your code.

Comment: Thankyou I will try this over the weekend and let you know. I don't have any code other than autogen code but happy to zip up entire project. My original XML works fine on my phone.. Just not my tablet.

Comment: Sorry, your code stopped any scrolling from taking place. The left LinearLayout shrunk down to the width of the EditText. The only way I could get it to start scrolling again was to increase the size of the buttons on the second page to my screen width and then the same thing started happening. Question though: If you change my original XML to use the screen dimensions of your device, do you actually have a problem or does it just work as you'd expect? I still feel the only way around this is to modify the HorizontalScrollView code itself.